# Perform keyboard shortcut programmatically - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm searching for a way to programmatically perform a keyboard shortcut, just as if the user had clicked the keys himself. That shortcut, however, is chosen by the user with a custom control called [ShortcutRecorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/).

Is there any way to take the info given by ShortcutRecorder (basically the key code and the flags, I think) and perform that shortcut?

Comment: Are you trying to do this within your own app, or system-wide?

Comment: @user1118321 Good question. System-wide. Like I said, just as if the user had done it himself. That means the shortcut will have its effect on the frontmost app, which might or might not be mine.

Comment: You'll probably need to use the [Accessability APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html) then.

Comment: @user1118321 Can you provide an example? I don't see how this API will do it.

Comment: I don't have an example, unfortunately. I think what you want to use is this: [`AXUIElementPostKeyboardEvent()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXUIElementPostKeyboardEvent). It's description reads "Posts keys to the specified application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CGEventPost()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCEDCEA) to post keyboard events system-wide, but the user will have to enable access for assistive devices in the Universal Access System Preferences pane.